# Does Network neutrality mean you can host a server?

Tags: web-hosting, isp

Does the Network neutrality ruleing mean that you can lawfully host a server on ANY ISP without paying extra?

Comment: It's ill-advised to take legal advice from complete strangers...

Comment: Where should this question go if it doesn't go here?

Comment: You should hire a lawyer and ask him or her.

Comment: Generally the answer is no. How your ISP handles data coming to an from your endpoint falls squarely under the contract that governs your connection (ToS or similar). Net neutrality is the idea that your ISP should not handle the data differently depend on where the other end of the connection is, or what kind of data is being transported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It does not mean you have to get a symmetric line. And end user connections are noramlyl slow on upload.

Yes. Like now, every ISP which offers hosting will offer you hosting.

Comment: So any isp that didnt allow, still doesnt allow, and any isp that does allow, still allows? So confusing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_neutrality